# Add a Maven assembly descriptor to my Unity3d project

Tags: xml, maven, unity-game-engine, maven-assembly-plugin

I need to create an archive of my builds folder. This folder is not related to my maven project.

So it seems like I need to use **maven-assembly-plugin** with a sepecific descriptor.

My problem is I don't know how to set the dependency between my pom.xml and my descriptor.xml

pom.xml :

```
<!-- archivage -->
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.3</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>make-assembly</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>single</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <!-- This is where we use our shared assembly descriptor -->
                  <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>unity-builds</descriptorRef>
                  </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
<!-- fin d'archivage -->
```

descriptor.xml

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
  <id>unity-builds</id>
  <formats>
    <format>zip</format>
  </formats>
  <fileSets>
    <fileSet>
      <includes>
        <include>pom.xml</include>
      </includes>
      <useDefaultExcludes>true</useDefaultExcludes>
    </fileSet>
    <fileSet>
      <directory>{WORKSPACE}/builds</directory>
      <useDefaultExcludes>true</useDefaultExcludes>
    </fileSet>
  </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

When I run this command : mvn clean install deploy , I had this problem

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.5.3:single (make-assembly) on project UnityAppTest: Error reading assemblies: Descriptor with ID 'unity-builds' not found -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `<descriptor-refs>`, it is for predefined (i.e. from a different module) descriptors.

What you need is `<descriptors>` instead:

```
<descriptors>
     <descriptor>path-to-unitybuild.xml</descriptor>
</descriptors>
```

Of course, you need to add the correct path to your descriptor.